# Query for date with join in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a two tables, `(1)` Table Clients and `(2)` Table Clients Action.

This is my sample table:

*Table Clients :*

```
id_clients | name | id_user_created | id_user_owner
    1        alfa         4                0
    2        beta         4                0
    3       charlie       5                0
```

*Table Clients Action :*

```
id_clients_action |       date_action   | id_clients | id_user_created | id_user_owner
         1           2015-09-04 17:09:37        1              4              0
         2           2015-09-05 18:19:07        1              4              0
```

And then, in a form, I have two input parameters, from date and to date.
These are my conditions :

```
Condition-1 : 
-id_user_created = 4
-from date = 2015-09-01 00:00:00
-end date = 2015-09-03 00:00:00
```

I want a result like this :

```
 id_clients | name | date 
     1        alfa   null
     2        beta   null
```

Next condition :

```
Condition-2 : 
-id_user_created = 4
-from date = 2015-09-01 00:00:00
-end date = 2015-09-22 00:00:00
```

I want a result like this :

```
id_clients | name | date 
    1        alfa   2015-09-04 17:09:37
    1        alfa   2015-09-05 18:19:07
    2        beta   null
```

Below is my query, but I still have a true date when I want with the result from my condition. Please give me a true query.

```
select B.id_clients, B.id_user_created, B.name, A.date_action as  lastActionDate
from clients_action as A
right join clients as B on A.id_clients=B.id_clients
where 
B.id_clients in 
(
     select id_clients 
     from clients_action where 
     date_action between '2015-09-01 00:00:00' and '2015-09-03 00:00:00' and id_user_owner = '0'
)
or
B.id_clients in 
(
    select id_clients 
    from clients 
     where 
    id_user_created = '4' and id_user_owner = '0'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct
a.id_clients,a.name,
case when b.id_clients_action=2 then b.date_action else null end as date
from clients a
left join clients_action b on a.id_user_created=b.id_user_created
```

Comment: sorry, id_clients_action is dinamic... :(